# Lightswitch HTML - changing currency depending on field within a table

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I have the following scenario:

I have a table called OrderLines, which contains information such as

- Part Name
- List Price
- Currency

Now from this information, I want to be able to change the text in the table view to resemble to Currency. Currently by default I can determine 1 currency, which I have stated as GBP, so when Lightswitch sees the currency value, it adds in GBP.

I want to be able to change this!!

on the "Edit PostRender Code" block, is it possible to use the `contentItem.dataBind` function in order to change this, based upon its currency field associated to that particular item?

Thankyou for any help, and hopefully this is possible.. (these should be in dollars based on the Currency file associated to this line within the table)

[image]

as you can see above, the OrderlIne table is in a table view on the "Orders" screen
[image]

code used:

```
myapp.ViewProjectOrder.ListPrice_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {
    contentItem.dataBind("value", function (value) {
        if (value) {
            if (contentItem.screen.OrderLines.Currency == "GBP") {
                $(element).text("£ " + value);
            }
            else if (contentItem.screen.OrderLines.Currency == "CAD") {
                $(element).text("$ " + value);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Lightswitch sees the ListPrice as a decimal currently, as if I set it as Currency, it always displays the currency prefix I set, Thats why there are pound symbols in the table above, I have since changed this to decimal to see it that works with no luck:
[image]

if i step into the code it doesnt find a value for the currency using the code:

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you using the Money type for your List Price, or double?

Comment: i have an sql server back end and have been using decimal, I never thought of trying other types, do you think this would work?

Comment: I don't think using the built in Money type is great for an app with multiple currencies. If I remember correctly it uses some locale information to display the amount, but not necessarily the currency symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set up a similar example and used a double for the ListPrice, and a string for the currency. I believe this is a safer approach to use than using the built in Money type.

The code below is for the View screen, it can be adjusted slightly to work on the Browse screen. You bind to the value of the ListPrice value changing and set the appropriate currency symbol. In general, I'd recommend having a more general function return the symbol for the currency's ISO code. You'd also probably want to set up a similar binding for when the currency is changed.

```
myapp.ViewProjectOrder.ListPrice_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {
    contentItem.dataBind("value", function (value) {
        if (value) {
            if ( contentItem.screen.ProjectOrder.Currency == "GBP" ) {
                $(element).text("£ " + value);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Assuming a more complicated case of a Project item that can contain more than one OrderLine, to display the order line details when viewing the Project's collection of OrderLines, you would need to alter the postRender code for the collection's row template. The following code should give you a starting point to format the values:

```
myapp.ViewProject.rows_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {
    contentItem.dataBind("value", function (value) {
        if (value) {
            var tags = element.children;
            var searchText = contentItem.value.ListPrice;

            for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
                if (tags[i].textContent == searchText) {

                    if (contentItem.value.Currency == "GBP") {
                        tags[i].textContent = "£ " + tags[i].textContent;
                    }
                    else if (contentItem.value.Currency == "USD") {
                        tags[i].textContent = "$ " + tags[i].textContent;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: i am just implementing this now, will get back to you with a response shortly

Comment: im afraid its not working, ive added the results above

Comment: Despite your ListPrice being stored as a double on the backend, something on the front end is interpreting your double value as a currency (likely using your locale). What control are you using to display this data? I'd recommend you set up the simple example I mentioned with the native LS screens and confirm that it works, it only takes 5 minutes.

Comment: Specifically, I'm trying to understand why your ListPrice is being interpreted automatically as a currency (specifically GBP by default), when its configured on your back end as a double. Did you configure anything on the front end to interpret it that way?

Comment: before yes, i set it as money with lightswitch and the default currency was "£", now I have changed this to resemble decimal and still no change, other than there now being no symbol in front of the decimal value

Comment: Can you confirm that Currency is a field on OrderLine (its not shown in your screenshot)? The only other reason I can think of is that it is showing up as undefined is because its not a required field and you haven't set it for that particular item. Let me know.

Comment: Spotted the issue, your screen object is ProjectOrder, not OrderLines. I've adjusted my answer.

Comment: Ahh bloody hell, will check this later today and get back to you, God I'm an idiot haha!! And thanks for spotting it

Comment: the currency is stored within the OrderLines table displayed, not in the ProjectOrders table. I want to be able to vary the currency based on the  OrderLines currency field if possible. I tried contentItem.screen.ProjectOrder.OrderLines.Currency but this did not work either

Comment: The focus of your question seems to have changed from formatting a single value to dealing with particular elements inside a collection. I've updated the answer to show how to get to the information in this case, but you'll need to work out how to map it to your elements, contentItems, and screens.

Comment: how have you got the top prefix (myapp.ViewProject.rows_postRender), have you made the table a custom control?

Comment: Im assuming that once I work out how to map my elements, this will work, so ill have a play and mark this answer as correct. thankyou for your help

Answer (score 2):

Since globalize.js is built in, you can render any currency with the following:

```
Globalize.format(Globalize.parseInt(value), 'c0', 'en-gb');
```

c0 stands for currency with 0 decimal digits. En-gb can be pulled in from db/other field - sorry GBP won't work.

Yes, parseInt/ParseFloat appears to be required, regardless of how you store the amount.

Long live LightSwitch!

Comment: thanks for the answer, much appreciated! and long live Lightswitch indeed. This is still leaps and bound ahead of many systems in use!